# How to deal with multiple config files in a actionscript 3.0 project

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm now working on multiple config files(about 16 .txt form files) in a actionscript 3.0 project. I think it is not good to load so many files. maybe I should package them into a swf(But I do not know how to do this) or do sth else.

I want to know what should I do with these files.
Thx so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're thinking that the number of files is too many for the application to handle, you're thinking about the problem the wrong way. The memory overhead will be higher with the SWF due to the headers, it'll also effect run-time performance as the Flash runtime has to parse SWF whereas it's easier for it to call on .txt files.

If you're thinking that your bin dist looks ridiculous with .txt files, and your exporter doesn't bundle them, try this resource : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html (the relevant section is at the bottom of the page under "Embedding all other file types"

tl;dr

I suggest you pass this if-else block.

```
if (You're looking to improve modularity, readability and clarity of resources but not speed){
// go here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html
}else{
// Keep using text files
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's just what I want to know

Answer (score 0):

XML is a great format to use with Actionscript 3. It is very simple to read, and is probably easier to work with than using standard text files.

Answer (score 0):

If You dont like to rewrite this files , pack them to ZIP and use FZIP library . You will load 1 file and have access to all files in synchro functions.

Like Joshua mentioned , You can also use XML or JSON .